# Interpreting a sufficient statistic

Tags: statistics

I am having trouble interpreting a sufficient statistic. I think I have a basic understanding of how to find them, how to show whether or not a given statistic is sufficient for a particular distribution, and a basic understanding of the mathematical definition.

However, I'm still not really sure how to interpret what sufficient statistics actually are and why they are meaningful. Can anybody help me out? What is a 'real-world' scenario in which they would be meaningful? How would you explain what a sufficient statistic is to a layperson?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a random variable $X$ defined by a normal distribution. What would you need to graph out this normal distribution?

You would need its mean and variance. When you try to calculate the sufficient statistics for the normal distribution, this is what you get -- that you need two statistics for the distribution, and that they are the mean and the variance.

Sufficient statistics are things that can *define* the distribution completely.